# Where to find the LSA exporting requirements from the USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, aircraft-purchase

I'm planning to visit the US to buy an [LSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-sport_aircraft) (light sport aircraft) then export it to Saudi Arabia, I'm not a US citizen, where to find the requirements?

Comment: Buy it Then Export it :)

Comment: Export it where?

Comment: To Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Appendix 2 of AC 21-2](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/international/export_aw_proc/sp_req_import/), and select Saudi Arabia from the drop down menu.

For example:

> It will be the responsibility of the Saudi Arabian importer to ensure that the nationality and registration marks are properly displayed on the aircraft **prior to departure from the exporter's base** and to ensure that the necessary flight documents are installed and carried in the aircraft during the delivery flight.

The full document lists all the requirements, too many to copy and paste here. For the regulations, that would be [Title 14, Code of Federal Regulations (14 CFR) part 21, subpart L](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2002-title14-vol1/pdf/CFR-2002-title14-vol1-part21-subpartL.pdf) (.pdf).